# Regex disallow white Spaces at beginning and at end

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

i have this regex:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,26})
```

Password must obey the following rules:

1. cannot contain white spaces at the beginning or at the end.
2. must contain at least one number.
3. must contain at least 1 capital letter.
4. must contain at least 1 small letter.
5. must contain at least special character(!@#$%^&*).
6. must be at least 8 characters min and max 26.

every thing works OK, but i cant disallow white spaces at beginning and at the end..

Any advise?
using javascript regex test..

Comment: C# and JavaScript implement two different regex standards.

Comment: I'm thinking you don't need the c# tag at all

Comment: @KSib as i mentioned, i need javascript regex test, thnx

Comment: @roydukkey thats right, i remove c# tag, thnx

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative lookahead/lookbehind next to the begin/end string anchor points to accomplish this:

`^(?!\s)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*]).{8,26}(?<!\s)$`

Answer (score 0):

You can preserve your lookahead logic and add the couple of conditions you are missing like this:

```
(?=\S)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,26})(?=.*\S$).*
```

(?=\S) => Must start with a non whitespace char.

(?=.*\S$) => Must end with a non whitespace char.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an extra positive lookahead `(?=\S.{6,24}\S$)` to assert that the string starts and ends with a non-whitespace character `\S` and update the quantifier to reflect the numbers of characters to `{6,24}`.

If your password could contain only the characters that you use in the lookaheads instead of matching all characters including whitespaces, you could use a character class again containing all the allowed characters.

Your regex could look like:

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])(?=\S.{6,24}\S$)[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VauWuy/1)